# How to skip the max function which has only one entry when i do a group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a requirement where I do a group by the table

**Table**

```
Name  salary
------------
abc   10000
abc    1000
def     100
```

Query:

```
select max(salary) 
from table 
group by Name
```

Result:

```
abc 10000
def   100
```

I don't want 'def' to be displayed since it's a single entry in the table. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your text is better than images... I will revert your edit

Comment: To filter rows you use `WHERE`, to filter aggregates you use `HAVING`.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a [`HAVING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause.

> Having specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate.
>   HAVING can be used only with the SELECT statement. HAVING is typically
>   used with a GROUP BY clause. When GROUP BY is not used, there is an
>   implicit single, aggregated group.

```
select 
   Name
  ,max(salary) 
from table 
group by Name having count(*) > 1
```

This will only return the aggregates for names that have more than 1 row, which seems to be what you want.

**EXAMPLE**

```
declare @table table (name varchar(16), salary int)
insert into @table
values
('abc',10000),
('abc',1000),
('def',100),
('xxf',100)

select 
    Name
    ,max(salary) 
from @table 
group by Name 
having count(*) > 1
```